# Auditing specific SAM_USER events in Windows 2012 R2 Active Directory

Tags: windows, audit, active-directory, windows-server

I'm trying to create logs in Windows Event Viewer for when a user uses "net user /domain [USER]".

So far what I've done was enable the **Audit SAM event** in Local Group Policy, and it appears to work. However, I want to configure the audit to trigger an event only when very **specific** accounts are touched with the above command. If possible, the only event that I'm interested in is EventID 4661 SAM_USER.

For example, if a user uses net user /domain Administrator, I would like a event to be triggered, but not for net user /domain JohnDoe.

I could just audit everyone like I am doing right now, but there are just too many logs being created.

I tried following the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841001/event-ids-560-and-562-appear-many-times-in-the-security-event-log

But it appears that these methods are for older servers.

I want to apply the auditing on specific users that will trigger the event. Not just when anyone is touched.

[image]